# md-radio-group in horizontal layout have to set dynamic repeat column count

Tags: angularjs

we need a radio button list with horizontal layout with 2 columns.

We will specify dynamically number of columns for each row.

Is there is any way to specify number of columns.

We tried to put  when $index % 2 == 0.

The md-radio-group should like this image ->
[md-radio-group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff23D.png)

But we don't know where to put it.

```js
         angular
            .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
            .controller('radioButtonsController', radioButtonsController);

         function radioButtonsController ($scope) {
            $scope.radioData = [
               { label: 'Apple', value: 'Apple' },
               { label: 'Banana', value: 'Banana' },
               { label: 'Mango', value: 'Mango', isDisabled: true },
               { label: 'Orange', value: 'Orange' }
            ];
            $scope.group = 'Banana';
         }
```

```html
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      
        
   </head>
   
   <body ng-app = "firstApplication"> 
      <div id = "radioButtonsContainer" ng-controller = "radioButtonsController as ctrl"
         layout = "column" ng-cloak>
         <p>Selected Value: <span>{{ group }}</span> </p>
         
         <md-radio-group ng-model = "group" class = "md-primary"  layout="row">
            <md-radio-button ng-repeat = "d in radioData"
               ng-value = "d.value"
               ng-disabled = " d.isDisabled "
               ng-class = "{'md-align-top-left': $index==1}" >
               {{ d.label }}<br/>
            </md-radio-button>
         </md-radio-group>
         
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you meant by each row ?  do you have more than one radioData ?

Comment: The md-radio-group should like this image -> md-radio-group https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff23D.png